# Yoneda embedding preserves finite coproducts

Tags: category-theory, products, yoneda-lemma

For the Yoneda Embedding, where $\mathcal{T}$ is an algebraic theory,
$$
Y_\mathcal{T}: \mathcal{T}^\mathrm{op} \to Alg \mathcal{T}
$$
it is claimed that $Y_\mathcal{T}$ preserves finite coproducts. The argument provided is as follows
[image]

I am not quite sure how the last line proves that $\mathcal{T}(t_1 \times t_2, -)$ is a co-product of $\mathcal{T}(t_1, -)$ and $\mathcal{T}(t_2, -)$. It seems that all that is shown is
$$
[Y_\mathcal{T}(t_1 + t_2), A] \cong [\mathcal{T}(t_1 \times t_2 , -), A]\cong A(t_1 \times t_2) \cong A(t_1) \times A(t_2) \cong [\mathcal{T}(t_1, -) , A] \times [\mathcal{T}(t_2, -) , A] \cong [\mathcal{T}(t_1, -)\times \mathcal{T}(t_2, -)  , A]\cong [Y_\mathcal{T}(t_1)\times Y_\mathcal{T}( t_2), A] .
$$
But I am not sure how to use that to show the claimed sentence.

Comment: Have you tried to use the first isomorphism for the latter two $A$'s?

Comment: @AndreaMarino In that case, I would end up with $$A(t_1) \times A(t_2) \cong [T(t_1, -), A] \times [T(t_2, -), A]? $$

Comment: One question: what book is that?

Comment: @azif00 Algebraic theories by Vitale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last two isomorphims are wrong, or more precisely, the second-to-last isomorphism is wrong. The universal property of the coproduct gives you an isomorphism
$$[\mathcal{T}(t_1, -) , A] \times [\mathcal{T}(t_2, -) , A] \cong [\mathcal{T}(t_1, -)+ \mathcal{T}(t_2, -)  , A] = [Y_\mathcal{T}(t_1)+Y_\mathcal{T}(t_2),A],$$
which concludes the proof.

Comment: I see, one last question: How do I conclude $$[Y_T(t_1+ t_2), A] \cong [Y_T(t_1)+Y_T(t_2),A] \implies Y_T(t_1+t_2) \cong Y_T(t_1) + Y_T(t_2)$$ Is it simply the $$H^P \cong H^Q \iff P \cong Q$$ where $P = Y_T(t_1+t_2)$ and $Q = Y_T(t_1)+Y_T(t_2)$.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.